# A limit of a sequence statistifying $S_{n} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}})=a_1+a_2+...+a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Sequence $\{a_n\}$ is a positive sequence and satisfies $S_{n} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}})$ where $S_n = a_1+a_2+...+a_n$. Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_{n+1}*(S_{n}-S_{n-1})$

Comment: the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ seems to converge to zero while the sum $S_{n}$ diverges... but can't figure out the value the product of the two converges into...

Comment: it seems that $a_1 = 1$ since $S_1 = a_1$ and after a long time with a calculator, the answer seems like 0.5, but it's hard to solve it mathematically(elegantly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint:
 since $a_{1}=1$
$$a_{n}=S_{n}-S_{n-1}$$
then we have
$$2S_{n}=S_{n}-S_{n-1}+\dfrac{1}{S_{n}-S_{n-1}}\Longrightarrow S^2_{n}-S^2_{n-1}=1$$
so
$$S_{n}=\sqrt{n},$$
so
$$S_{n+1}(S_{n}-S_{n-1})=\sqrt{n+1}(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1})\to \dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: And title changed to "not too hard-to-solve"

Comment: @MichaelGaluza suggestion accepted!

Comment: Is there an easy way of showing the convergence last step without using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ ?

Comment: Multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}$